# mod_rewrite .htaccess problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have the following lines in my htaccess to rewrite the css files to another location:

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] OR
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^\\/?(.*)\.(css|js)$ public/$2/$1.$2 [L,NC,NE]
```

but when the site tries to load the files, there is an errer of a misconfiguration. the actual problem is the dot between $1 and $2. i think when the server finds the file then it gets into an infinite loop.

does anyone know the reason for that error?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I looked at the syntax for some of this, but I thought that the `OR` would be within the brackets.  That said, that is part of your problem; you need both `RewriteCond` conditions to be true.  Also, you need the file actually to be present; if the file is not found, you will enter an infinite loop anyway.  Another approach might be:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(css|js)/ - [NC,L]
```

prior to the `RewriteCond` directives so that nothing in `public/css` or `public/js` gets rewritten, regardless of whether it is there.

Also, in per-directory context (i.e., .htaccess), the value that `RewriteRule` matches does not begin with a slash.  That's not causing your problem, but it could save you a few characters and make your regex simpler to read.

Answer (score 2):

Write your rule like this to avoid infinite looping:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*)\.(css|js)$ public/$2/$1.$2 [L,NC]
```

Negative look ahead will prevent infinite looping for you.

Comment: even "more beatiful" than the other solution =)

Answer (score 0):

It gets into infinite loop because the directory that you are redirecting also satisfies the regex.

Comment: yeah. i thought of something like that. so at least i know know where to look at.